# Sort WooCommerce cart by category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I already found a snippet to sort the checkout cart alphabetically. This works perfect but as mentioned I try to sort and group my products by category.

Is there anyone who could tweak the following snippet so it sorts the products by category?

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', 'bbloomer_sort_cart_items_alphabetically' );
 
function bbloomer_sort_cart_items_alphabetically() {
     
   global $woocommerce;
    
   // READ CART ITEMS
   $products_in_cart = array();
   foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $item ) {
      $products_in_cart[ $key ] = $item['data']->get_title();
   }
    
   // SORT CART ITEMS
   natsort( $products_in_cart );
    
   // ASSIGN SORTED ITEMS TO CART
   $cart_contents = array();
   foreach ( $products_in_cart as $cart_key => $product_title ) {
      $cart_contents[ $cart_key ] = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_key ];
   }
   $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents = $cart_contents;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to grouped cart items by categories, add follows code snippet -

```
function woocommerce_before_cart_contents(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $cat_wisw_pros = array();
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $cat_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
        foreach ( $cat_ids as $id ) {
            $cat_wisw_pros[$id][$cart_item_key] = $cart_item;
        }
    }
    ksort( $cat_wisw_pros ); // Cat ID wise sort
    $grouped_cart_items = array();
    foreach ( $cat_wisw_pros as $cat_id => $cart_items ) {
        foreach ( $cart_items as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            if( !array_key_exists( $cart_item_key, $grouped_cart_items ) )
                $grouped_cart_items[$cart_item_key] = $cart_item;
        }
    }
    $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents = $grouped_cart_items;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents', 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfect.
The reason for the sorting is, that we want to pick the articles in our store in the ordered by category way

And what I thaught is that the order confirmation mail is automatically sorted by categeory as well when the cart will be sorted by category.
Do you have a snippet to sort the confirmation mail by category as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the category ids with the method `get_category_ids()` as defined in the class `WC_Product`

```
$item['data']->get_category_ids()
```

but this gives you back an `array`, so you need to handle getting the id, e.g.

```
$ids = $item['data']->get_category_ids();
$id  = $ids[ 0 ];
```

and transforming to a string, e.g.

```
$term_obj = get_term( $id, 'product_cat' );
$name     = $term_obj->name;
```

you could then do

```
$products_in_cart[ $key ] = $name;
```

and by the same logic used in the code in your question sort by category.

There are several things to consider though, this does not handle items being in multiple categories, it just gets the first by using index 0. Additionally, this has no extra logic of sorting, if there are multiple products in the same category.

Please note, this is untested and merely an idea of an approach of how this could be handled.